# Button text not visible when using android:singleLine and android:autoLink

Tags: android, expandablelistview, textview, android-xml, android-button

I use the following style to layout a button:

```
<style name="Button.Web" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:autoLink">web</item>
</style>
```

The button itself is nested in some `LinearLayouts` which are wrapped in a `ExpandableListView`:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_web"
    style="@style/Button.Web" />
```

In a subclass of `BaseExpandableListAdapter` I dynamically set the text for each instance of the button:

```
Button buttonWeb = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_web);
buttonWeb.setText("http://www.example.com/" + page);
```

When I expand an item of the `ExpandableListView` the button is shown (see button in "Number 2" and "Number 4"). However there is **no text rendered** on it. The moment I touch the button the **text appears** (see button in "Number 3").

[image: ExpandableListView]

---

## Experiments

- I noticed from playing around with the style settings that the **combination** of [`android:singleLine`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:singleLine) and [`android:autoLink`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:autoLink) produces the described behavior.
- I found out that `android:singleLine` is actually **deprecated** as [stated in the API documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#singleLine). Therefore, I tested [`android:maxLines`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:maxLines) set to `1` as suggested there. This results in a button with text of **multiple lines which scroll vertically**.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is quite a bit old but I faced similar problems. In my case I had to set the "android:textColorLink" attribute in the xml additionally to the autoLink attribute. The behaviour is the same for TextView.

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:autoLink="phone|email"
    android:textColorLink="@color/yourDesiredLinkColor"/>
```

Probablby it won't help you but hopefully someone else :)